# source .bashrc does nothing

Tags: bash, bashrc, virtualenvwrapper

after installing virtualenvwrapper I edited .bash_profile and added those lines (it was blank actually)

```
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

then I sourced .bashrc the normal is to apply the changes and output some lines on terminal
but nothing happens

what is the problem?

Comment: if you edited .bash_profile, why did you source .bashrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bash_profile` is used just by login-shells. If you start a terminal/xterm/konsole on your Desktop, this file isn't sourced.

The file you probably want to use is *~/.bashrc*. Just copy the systems */etc/bash/bashrc* to your home directory:

```
cp /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

and append your information to that file:

```
echo 'export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but there is no directory called /etc/bash

Comment: @UXE he meant `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes, sorry checked the file on the wrong distribution.